# WPF: Can't figure out focus

Tags: wpf, vb.net

WPF focusing is drivin me nuts :(

In a brand new test WPF project, I have this Window...

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtStatic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False">
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0 0 1 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="False">
                <ContentControl x:Name="con" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this codebehind...

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.Name = "txtDynamic"
        Me.con.Content = txt
        txt.Focus()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Two questions...

1. When the project above is started an the MainWindow is shown, why can't I start typing in the textbox created at runtime (txtDynamic)? It seams like it already has focus.
2. If i run the project and click the txtStatic textbox and then press TAB it seams like the dynamic (txtDynamic) textbox gets focus, but I can't type - I have to press TAB once more. Why this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you contentcontrol Focusable to false

```
<ContentControl Focusable="False" x:Name="con" />
```

and in code behind add ,sorry it is in C#

```
 var txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Name = "txtDynamic";
    con.Content = txt;
    txt.Focus();

   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
   DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
   new Action(delegate()
   {
       txt.Focus();
   }));
```

Comment: Wow thanks ... I thought it would be easy to go from WinForms to WPF ... think again ;) ... Thanks again!!!